# dynamic programming - what's the asymptotic runtime?

Tags: java, math, runtime, dynamic-programming, asymptotic-complexity

I'm teaching myself dynamic programming. It's almost magical. But seriously. Anyway, the problem I worked out was : `Given a stairs of N steps and a child who can either take 1, 2, or 3 steps at a time, how many different ways can the child reach the top step?`. The problem wasn't too hard, my implementation is below.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ChildSteps {
    private HashMap<Integer, Integer> waysToStep;

    public ChildSteps() {
        waysToStep = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    }

    public int getNthStep(int n) {
        if (n < 0) return 0; // 0 ways to get to a negative step

        // Base Case
        if (n == 0) return 1;

        // If not yet memorized
        if (!waysToStep.containsKey(n)) {
            waysToStep.put(n, getNthStep(n - 3) + getNthStep(n - 2) + getNthStep(n - 1));
        }

        return waysToStep.get(n);
    }
}
```

However, now I want to get the runtime. How should I figure this out? I am familiar (and not much more) with Akra-Bazzi and Master Theorem. Do those apply here?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Here it would seem that it could be: `T(N) = 3 * T(???) + O(1)` but I'm really not sure.

thanks guys.

Comment: Have you worked out the mathematical equation for this first?

Comment: No, I don't really know how. An equation for what, exactly?

Comment: Given N steps, if you can take m steps at a time, how many different ways can you reach the top.  Once you know the equation then you have made this a trivial problem.

Comment: Don't you mean given N steps and can take m or less steps (where m > 0 and m <= N)? that would make more sense in this problem.

Comment: Since he has three known values, just come up with a general equation for a particular m number of steps.

Comment: @JamesBlack yes, I just have no idea how to do that...

Comment: You can look at this for some ideas.  I am trying not to do your work for you. http://saliu.com/permutations.html#Permutation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a worst case scenario analysis it would be:

```
T(N) = N * (containsKey(N) + 8)
```

Assuming that containsKey = N (it is probably `N^2` or `Log(N)`) then this simplifies to `T(N) = N`.

You would have to find out the function for `containsKey(N)` to get the actual equation.

You're really over thinking this though; you don't need to do a algorithm analysis for this. Good quote for you: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"

Comment: Could you explain how you go to this line: `T(N) = N * (containsKey(N) + 8)`? and yeah I'm not really optimizing, I'm just trying to learn how to calculate asymptotic runtimes.